# HTML replaced by php output in browser when multipart form data is submitted to mysql using MAMP

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, mamp

I am getting an unexpected response from my browser when I submit a file using multipart/form-data.

The php script triggered by the action executes perfectly but the file prints echoed statements on a white background to my browser and replaces my HTML.

If I comment out my echo statements I just get a white screen.

I would prefer the script to just run in the background and not override my HTML.

I am using a localhost with MAMP.

Any thoughts?

My HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
    <title>See Me</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="seeMe.css" rel="stylesheet">

  </head>
  <body>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="seeMe.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="compatibility.js"></script>



    <div id="signInDiv">
        <form id="sign_In_Form">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" name="username"  class="form-control"  id="usernameTextField" placeholder="Username" >
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" name="password"  class="form-control"  id="passwordTextField" placeholder="Password" >
            </div>
       </form>
       <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" onclick="signInUser(this)">Sign In</button>

     </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

My JS

```
var userSignedIn = 0;
var usernameString;
var picsArray;
function signInUser(id){
  var u = $( "#usernameTextField").val();
  var p = $( "#passwordTextField").val();


  //query database for user data and check for match
  var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {

              var foundUser =  xmlhttp.responseText;

              if (foundUser == "TRUE" ) {
                usernameString = u;
                userSignedIn = 1;

                showGalleryPage();

                }
                else{
                 alert("Username and Password do not match");
                }

              }
              else{
                //alert("Could not connect to account. Try again later.");
              }

        };
        xmlhttp.open("GET", "seeMeeSignIn.php?u=" + u + "&p=" + p, true);
        xmlhttp.send();


}




function showGalleryPage (id) {
  $( "div" ).remove();
  alert("about to getPics");
  getPics();

}



function getPics (id){
  var u = usernameString;

  var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {

            picsArray = $.parseJSON(xmlhttp.responseText);

           var imgagesHTML = "";
           for (var i = 0; i < picsArray.length; i++) {

            imgagesHTML = imgagesHTML + '<img src=' + picsArray[i] + ' alt="Mountain View" style="width:100px;height:100px;">';

           }

            var showGalleryHtml;
            showGalleryHtml = '<div id="galleryHeader">' + 
                    '</div>' +
                    '<div id="thumbnailGalleryView">'+ 
                      imgagesHTML +
                    '</div>'+
                    '<div id="addPicButton">'+
                      '<form action="seeMeAddPic.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">'+
                        '<input type="file" name="file">'+
                        "<input type='hidden' name='username' value= "+ usernameString + '>'+
                        '<input type="submit" onclick="showGalleryPage(this)">'+
                      '</form>'+
                    '</div>'+
                    '<div id="picToDisplayLabel">'+
                    '</div>'+
                    '<div id="picToDisplay">'+
                    '</div>'+
                    '<div id="checkboxToRandomize">'+
                    '</div>';

                    var $jshowGalleryHtml = $(showGalleryHtml);
                    $("body").append($jshowGalleryHtml);
              }
              else{
                //alert(xmlhttp.responseText);
              }

        };
        xmlhttp.open("GET", "seeMeGetPics.php?u=" + u, true);
        xmlhttp.send();

}
```

My PHP

```
<?php

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "root";
$dbname = "seemedb";

$db = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

if($db->connect_errno > 0){
    die('Unable to connect to database [' . $db->connect_error . ']');
}

$file = $_FILES['file'];
$name = $file['name'];
$user = $_POST['username'];


$path = "keepPicsHere/" . basename($name);
if (move_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'], $path)) {
    //echo "Move succeed";

} else {
    //echo "Move failed. Possible duplicate?";
}

$sql = "INSERT INTO imageData (userSubmitting, imagePath) VALUES ('".$user."', '" . $path . "')";

if ($db->query($sql) === TRUE) {
   // echo "New record created successfully";


} else {
   // echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

$db->close();

?>
```

Comment: post your php code here

Comment: I agree to @NaveedAhmed and please add your submit.php codes to your question

Comment: White/blank screen => http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php yet let's leave the guesswork out of things and post your full code. You tagged as php and mysql and javascript, but no code to support the question.

Comment: Are you clicking the button or hitting the enter key? Also, since you're using jQuery anyway, why not use jQuery's event handlers and ajax methods?

Comment: clicking the button.  I was thinking about using AJAX but I wasn't sure I could "move_uploaded_file" in php other than with form data .